# sum with coefficient similar to binomial

Tags: binomial-coefficients

$\sum_{l=0}^{k/2} \frac{k!}{(k-2l)!l!}$

I want to calculate the above sum. Its form is similar to that of binomial but not same.

How to calculate it? Am I in wrong path?(which means its solution is not relevant to binomial?)

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Answer (score 0):

$$1=1\\
1+1=2\\
1+6+1=8\\
1+10+5=16\\
1+15+15+1=32$$

isn't this enough ?

Comment: I`m sorry but I can`t understand how that numbers are related to the solution. Could you give me little bit more?

Comment: Last hint: Pascal.

Comment: I totally can`t understand what your intention is. I know that is pascal`s triangle. And I know it is related to binomial coefficient. But I can`t understand how that is related to my question. I tried as best as I can to change it into the form that fits it but I can`t. That`s why I questioned it here. I also can`t understand how the numbers you show is related to my question. I calculate the sum of my question when k = 0 , 1 ,2 ,3, 4 ... and it doesn`t fit yours at all.

Comment: ah... hey, are you thinking that my question is $\sum_{l=0}^{k/2} \frac{k!}{(k-2l)!(2l)!}$ ?

Comment: @kyle: bingo! :)